Google Ads API - Trying to access from service account
I am trying to pull data from Google Ads API to get campaign data without using OAuth Scopes and by just using a service account. Though I have put all the service account credential in my yaml file, I am getting "The Google account (@gmail.com user) that generated the OAuth access tokens is not associated with any Ads accounts." PLEASE HELP:)
CODE:
    from google.ads.googleads.client import GoogleAdsClient
    from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials

    def get_campaigns_with_service_account(path_to_credential_file):
  """Retrieves a list of campaigns using a service account.

  Args:
      client_id: The client ID of your Google Ads API credentials.
      client_secret: The client secret of your Google Ads API credentials (optional).
      refresh_token: The refresh token for your Google Ads API credentials (optional).
      developer_token: The developer token for your Google Ads API project.
      path_to_credential_file: The path to your service account key file in JSON format.
  """

  # Configure service account credentials
  credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file(
      path_to_credential_file,
      scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords'],  # Adjust scopes as needed
  )

  # Create Google Ads client using service account credentials
  client =GoogleAdsClient.load_from_storage("/content/drive/My Drive/Keys/google-ads.yaml")

  ga_service = client.get_service("GoogleAdsService", version="v16")  # Use CampaignService

  # Create a query to retrieve all campaigns
  query = ("SELECT campaign.id, campaign.name, campaign.status "
           "FROM campaign")

  # Get a response with campaign information
  customer_id = 'XXXXXX'  # Replace with your actual customer ID
  def stream_response(client, customer_id, query):
    return client.get_service("GoogleAdsService", version="v16").search_stream(customer_id=customer_id,       query=query)`
`

MY YAML FILE:
`# Developer token
##########################################################################################
# A developer token is required when making requests to the Google Ads API regardless of #
# whether you're using the OAuth2 or Service Account configurations. To obtain a         #
# developer token see:                                                                   #
# https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/first-call/dev-token                 #
##########################################################################################
    developer_token: {{token}}

# Use proto plus
##########################################################################################
# This parameter specifies whether the client library should return proto-plus messages  #
# or protobuf messages. This value should be explicitly set to either "True" or "False", #
# For more information on the differences between these two types, see our Protobuf      #
# Messages guide:                                                                        #
# https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/client-libs/python/protobuf-messages #
##########################################################################################
    use_proto_plus: False

# OAuth2 configuration
##########################################################################################
# The below configuration parameters are used to authenticate using the recommended      #
# OAuth2 flow. For more information on authenticating with OAuth2 see:                   #
# https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/oauth/overview                       #
##########################################################################################
#client_id: INSERT_ID_HERE
#client_secret: INSERT_SECRET_HERE
#refresh_token: INSERT_REFRESH_TOKEN_HERE

# Service Account configuration
##########################################################################################
# To authenticate with a service account add the appropriate values to the below         #
# configuration parameters and remove the three OAuth2 credentials above. The            #
# "json_key_file_path" value should be a path to your local private key json file, and   #
# "impersonated_email" should be the email address that is being used to impersonate the #
# credentials making requests. for more information on service accounts, see:            #
# https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/oauth/service-accounts.              #
# If you're authorizing with direct account access, then the "impersonated_email"        #
# configuration is optional.                                                             #
##########################################################################################
    json_key_file_path: /content/drive/My Drive/Keys/winged-woods-421416-bcf06a74b272.json
    impersonated_email: api-creds@winged-woods-xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com

# Login customer ID configuration
##########################################################################################
# Required for manager accounts only: Specify the login customer ID used to authenticate #
# API calls. This will be the customer ID of the authenticated manager account. It       #
# should be set without dashes, for example: 1234567890 instead of 123-456-7890. You can #
# also specify this later in code if your application uses multiple manager account +    #
# OAuth pairs.                                                                           #
##########################################################################################
login_customer_id: XXXXXXXX

# Logging configuration
##########################################################################################
# Below you may specify the logging configuration. This will be provided as an input to  #
# logging.config.dictConfig. Use the "level" block under the root logger configuration   #
# to adjust the logging level. Note in the "format" field that log messages are          #
# truncated to 5000 characters by default. You can change this to any length by removing #
# the ".5000" portion or changing it to a different number.                              #
# ########################################################################################
# logging:
  # version: 1
  # disable_existing_loggers: False
  # formatters:
    # default_fmt:
      # format: '[%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s] %(message).5000s'
      # datefmt: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
  # handlers:
    # default_handler:
      # class: logging.StreamHandler
      # formatter: default_fmt
  # loggers:
    # "":
      # handlers: [default_handler]
      # level: INFO

# Proxy configuration
##########################################################################################
# Below you can specify an optional proxy configuration to be used by requests. If you   #
# don't have username and password, just specify host and port.                          #
# ########################################################################################
# http_proxy: http://user:password@localhost:8000`



OUTPUT:
FaultMessage: The Google account (@gmail.com user) that generated the OAuth access tokens is not associated with any Ads accounts. Create a new account, or add the Google account to an existing Ads account.
  message: "The Google account (@gmail.com user) that generated the OAuth access tokens is not associated with any Ads accounts. Create a new account, or add the Google account to an existing Ads account."
}


Looks like you misunderstood the impersonation email purpose. The service account is used to impersonate an regular person who has access to the ads account. You cannot use a service account in a different way (the way you might expect).
See here: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/oauth/service-accounts#prerequisites
you're trying to impersonate the service account, not a real user. Which is why you're getting this error.
